# GIF images in a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to turn a small animated GIF into a background image of a button?
I've tried this:

```
$("#button").css('background-image', '~~.gif');
```

but it didnt work.

Comment: Backgrounds images do not animate.

Comment: @Diodeus - really? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wDmUn/

Comment: Try `$("#button").css( 'backgroundImage', 'url("~~.gif")' );`

Comment: Is it with html ok ?? or only with jquery ??

Comment: what kind of element is #button ? <button> <input type="button"> <a> ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#button').css('backgroundImage', 'url("anim.gif")');
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/W79dh/)

For `<input type="button" />` and `<button>` it works just fine too:

[**EXAMPLE2**](http://jsfiddle.net/W79dh/1)

Comment: `<button>` or `<input type="button" />`?

Comment: @Baadshah it's working for `<button>` and `<input type="button" />` [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/W79dh/1/)

Comment: was just making an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rufp9/1/

Comment: @Baadshah please check if there aren't other styles or scripts that are interfering with your element

Comment: @silentw yeah.Its working :)

Comment: @Baadshah If your problem is solved, accept the answer :)

Comment: ROFL..its not my question :) I can only upvote you :P

Comment: Ups, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

As j08691 said:

```
$("#button").css({"backgroundImage" : "url(anim.gif)"});
```

Comment: Not,working,please check.